# How to use .slice with media query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries

I'm trying to slice objects whenever the screen is 600px and down, I'm using this code in react to know if the screen is 600px or down

```
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(
    window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    window
    .matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
    .addEventListener('change', e => setMatches( e.matches ));
  }, []);
```

I'm trying to show pictures

```
return (
    <div className="shopsHomeFeedImgsCont">
      {shops.map((shop) => (

        <img className="shopsHomeFeedImgs"
        src={shop.shopPic} />
        
      )).slice(0, 2)}
    </div>
);
```

My question is how slice(0, 2) only when the screen is 600px and down?

Comment: What data do you want to perform the `slice(0, 2)` operation? Show the minimal, complete code

Comment: @slideshowp2 i edited the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `matches` state to make your `shops` data depend on the match query result.

```
const shopsToBeRendered = matches ? shops.slice(0, 2) : shops;

return (
    <div className="shopsHomeFeedImgsCont">
      {shopsToBeRendered.map((shop) => (
        <img className="shopsHomeFeedImgs" src={shop.shopPic} />
      ))}
    </div>
);
```